# Suddenly can't read/write to file

Tags: java, android, file

I'm making an android application, which saves data to a file in the settings activity.
I made some custom functions to ease writing my files, they're in a class all my activities inherit from, including the settings activity.

Custom functions:

```
public void WriteToFile(String filename, String tag, String value) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput(filename + ".txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
        writer.write(ReadFile(filename + ".txt") + tag + ":" + value + ";");
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Error writing: ", e.toString());
    }
}

public void WipeFile(String filename) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput(filename + ".txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
        writer.write("");
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Error writing: ", e.toString());
    }
}

public String ReadFile(String filename) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput(filename + ".txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[10000];
        String content = "", readString;
        int charRead;
        while ((charRead = InputRead.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
            readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
            content += readString;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        return content;
    } catch (Exception e) { WipeFile(filename); return ""; }
}

public String FileValue(String filename, String tag, String defaultValue) {
    String[] content = ReadFile(filename + ".txt").split(";");
    for (String pair : content) {
        if (pair.split(":")[0].equals(tag)) return pair.split(":")[1];
    } WriteToFile(filename, tag, defaultValue); return defaultValue;
}
```

Settings activity:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ToolbarTitle = "Settings";
    ActivityID = R.layout.activity_settings;
    ToolbarID = R.id.settings_toolbar;
    ToolbarIcon = R.mipmap.settings_icon;
    ActivityLayout = R.id.settings_layout;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (prefs.getInt("LoggedinID", 0) == 0) findViewById(R.id.settings_user).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.settings_lowBattery, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(FileValue("settings", "Alert", "20%"));
    Spinner battery = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.settings_battery));
    battery.setAdapter(adapter);
    battery.setSelection(spinnerPosition);

    ((Switch) findViewById(R.id.settings_notifications)).setChecked(FileValue("settings", "Notifications", "1").equals("1"));

    findViewById(R.id.settings_ads).setVisibility((FileValue("settings", "Ads", "1").equals("1") ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE));
}

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public void Apply(View view) {
    WipeFile("settings");
    WriteToFile("settings", "Notifications", (((Switch) findViewById(R.id.settings_notifications)).isChecked() ? "1" : "0"));
    WriteToFile("settings", "Alert", ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.settings_battery)).getSelectedItem().toString());
}

public void Ads(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Just a prank, bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    WriteToFile("settings", "Ads", "0");
}
```

What's weird is that it all worked when it was messy and not in custom functions, any idea why?

The problem seems to occur in the ReadFile function, where InputRead.read(inputBuffer) returns -1 (No data in file).
I have no idea how to even check where the problem lies, when writing to the file or when reading from it....

Thanks ahead

PROBLEM SOLVED
1. The ReadFile function that was inside the writer.write function couldn't open the file and read it since the writer kept it open for itself.
2. That same ReadFile function was provided with (filename + ".txt"), and added ".txt" to it as well.

Comment: are you sutre that the file is in place? themes like there is no file you are looking for.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Well, it did work before when there wasn't a file, It simply created one.  
Just in case, how do I make sure the file is there or create it?

Comment: It would be good to see the old code that was working. There are w peoblems i can think of... 1) the file was not closed one time you ran it, and hence you cannot add any info. 2) the file is there, you just arent seeing it in your file explorer because it hasnt updated.

Comment: @bremen_matt Unfortunately I removed the code.... 1) In case that's the problem, how do I close the file now that it's un-editable? 2) Sorry didn't understand that one

Comment: Just a tip on your first point... during development, i work out out of a dropbox folder since dropbox automatically saves recent changes in the web interface.

Comment: 2) How do you know that the file isnt there... are you using adb or a file explorer like ES

Comment: @bremen_matt Yeah, I really should keep versions when changing the code, but this was part of the same development, didn't consider it a change more than a build finishing.... Oh well, lesson learned. Well, I have no file explorer, no....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem might be in how you are appending to file...

Internally your write function opens the file, then before closing it, your read function opens the same file and closes it. It could be that either the read function is failing when it tries to open the file because it is already open, but not closed. OR it could be that when the read function closes the file it also closes the file for the write function...

So the problem seems to be that you want to append to the file in your write function, but you are implementing it poorly. You do not need to rewrite the contents to file. You just need to find the proper flag to open the file for appending.

Comment: Well, that was the problem, thank you (And also one small thing that I caught from your comment, two birds with one stone I guess). Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **java.util.Properties** for your settings. It is like a Map<String, String>.

To load all your settings, use **load(Reader reader)**.

To save all your settings, use **save(OutputStream out, String comments)**.

Comment: Oh.. Didn't know that exists (It's obvious I'm very new at this, right?), will do in future projects, thank you